# Search dates within

Tags: mysql

I have a date collection where has from and to

```
 from                       to
2018-01-24 14:02:00 | 2018-01-29 16:02:00
2018-01-25 16:02:00 | 2018-01-29 16:02:00
2018-01-26 14:02:00 | 2018-01-29 16:02:00
2018-01-27 14:02:00 | 2018-01-30 16:02:00
```

edited: my parameter is only 1 value which is the datetime today

I would like to search where the datetime is with in this to from and to
how can I do that?

Table: `tbl_announcements`
columns, from, to

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM tbl_announcements WHERE \`from\` >= <YourDateTime> AND \`to\` <= <YourDateTime>`?

Comment: @Terry that wont do since I have 2 date range that only will work if I have one date column

Comment: compare dates with each other? greater than and less than? wouldn't it work?

Comment: as @Terry stated above, you can use your 2nd date range in 
'AND to <= <Your2ndDateTime>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as they stated above

```
 from                       to
2018-01-24 14:02:00 | 2018-01-31 16:02:00
2018-01-25 16:02:00 | 2018-01-31 16:02:00
2018-01-26 14:02:00 | 2018-01-31 16:02:00
2018-01-27 14:02:00 | 2018-01-31 16:02:00
```

assuming my date is `2018-01-28 00:00:00`

`where sbdt.FromDate >= @targetDateBegin and   sbdt.ToDate <= @targetDateEnd`

this will not work because

`sbdt.FromDate >= 2018-01-28 00:00:00` nothing is true look

```
2018-01-24 14:02:00 >= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
2018-01-25 16:02:00 >= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
2018-01-26 14:02:00 >= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
2018-01-27 14:02:00 >= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
```

all date are less than the parameter date

`sbdt.ToDate <= 2018-01-28 00:00:00` nothing is true look

```
2018-01-31 16:02:00 <= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
2018-01-31 16:02:00 <= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
2018-01-31 16:02:00 <= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
2018-01-31 16:02:00 <= 2018-01-28 00:00:00 false
```

all date are greater than the parameter date

that logic will only work if I compare this to a one specific date only but I have 2 date range

but thank god I found a very short and easy solution which using between

`2018-01-28 00:00:00 between sbdt.FromDate and sbdt.ToDate` if I compare this to a one specific date only but I have 2 date range

but thank god I found a very short and easy solution which using between

`2018-01-28 00:00:00 between sbdt.FromDate and sbdt.ToDate`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would really recommend, you NOT name your column from, as it is a protected identifier for table selection.
I don't know if SQL will let you name your column that, but I would rename it asap, if you did. It will make your code more readable, if nothing else.

Generally try to avoid using names in coding that matches strongly typed words. you will save yourself a lot of tears in the end.

Lets say your table is:

Table SearchByDateTime

### Id(PK) | FromDate | ToDate |

Then your query would be (In Pseudo code form):

```
declare @targetDate Datetime;

Set @targetDate = "2017-01-01 00:00:00"

Select * from SearchByDateTime sbdt

where sbdt.FromDate >= @targetDate and  sbdt.ToDate <= @targetDate
```

You could also do, if you have two target values:

```
declare @targetDateBegin Datetime;
declare @targetDateEnd Datetime;

Set @targetDateBegin = "2017-01-01 00:00:00"
Set @targetDateBegin = "2017-02-01 00:00:00"


where sbdt.FromDate >= @targetDateBegin and   sbdt.ToDate <= @targetDateEnd
```

You aren't however super specific in your question, if you would clarify, I could be much more accurate in my response...